# WPF: Detect when selected item changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, listbox, selecteditem

I have a control that is data-bound to a `ListBox`. All of the bound properties are being updated correctly. However, the control needs to know when the selected item changes so that it can do some other cleanup. Is there an event that covers this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also bind to the `SelectedItem` property, say with `ICollectionView.CurrentItem`, and set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property to True.

Comment: I don't see how that will give me a current item changed event.

Comment: You can listen to the underlying collection's `CurrentChanged` event.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I use the CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataContext) to get the view, and that view is your ICollectionView.

Comment: Stupid website. It won't let me give you an up vote unless you edit your answer.... or I can edit it without changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event in ListBox.

Comment: No good. The detail control and the listbox don't know anything about each other. I need to do this entirely within the detail control.